# Constructing an almost contained set from a family of sets with strong finite intersection property.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I don't even know if this is true but I have a feeling I've read it's true somewhere. A counterexample or a proof would be equally welcome, or a link to where I can find more information. (Maybe the theorem has a name? I have this feeling...)

For $\{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in\omega}$ countable family of subsets of naturals with strong finite intersection property, there exists $X_{\lambda}\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that $X_{\lambda}\setminus\ X_{\alpha}$ is finite for all $\alpha\in\omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Given $\{n_i:i<k\}\subseteq\omega$ for some $k\in\omega$, let

$$n_k=\min\left(\left(\bigcap_{i\le k}X_i\right)\setminus\{n_k:i<k\}\right)\;;$$

then $X=\{n_k:k\in\omega\}$ is almost contained in each $X_k$.